# Texto encima de imagen

Tags: html, css, imagen

estoy usando bootstrap 5, quiero poner los titulos superpuestos de las fotos en su posicion inferior, nose como realizarlo. (Que se vean el texto encima de la foto)

Aqui el codigo:

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
                                <div class="popup" id="popup">
                                    <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                                    <img src="img/global.jpg" id="img" href="img1.php">
                                    <img src="img/global.jpg" id="img" href="img2.php">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h1>xx</h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h1>xx</h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Por favor checa esta guia para hacer una buena pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres sobreponer el texto sobre la imagen, te recomiendo el uso del componente [Card de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/#image-overlays) (en este enlace encontrarás información ampliada y ejemplos más completos) de este modo, usando las clases `card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="popup" id="popup">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Cerrar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card ">
              <img class="card-img" src="https://perfumesyfragancias.online/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/poire.jpg" id="img" href="img1.php">
              <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                <h1 class="card-title">xxxxxxxxx</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img" src="https://perfumesyfragancias.online/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/poire.jpg" id="img2" href="img2.php">
              <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                <h1 class="card-title">yyyyyyy</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad, no entiendo tu pregunta demasiado bien, pero intuyo que lo que quieres es que aparezcan los títulos, y debajo las imágenes. Para ello simplemente cambia el orden en que tienes las imágenes y los títulos:

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <div class="popup" id="popup">
            <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>xx</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>xx</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="img/global.jpg" id="img" href="img1.php">
            <img src="img/global.jpg" id="img" href="img2.php">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tal vez quieras centrar los títulos también por lo que tendrás que usar css o cualquier otra herramienta. En caso de que esto no es lo que deseas, por favor pulsa en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/536205/edit) y especifíca un poco mas.

Comment: Editado, mira a ver ahora, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que quieres es algo así:

```
<style>
*{margin:0; padding:0;} /* Sekector universal, quitamos espaciado automatico */

.test{
    width:400px;
    margin:10px; /* Espaciado a los lados de los elementos .TEST */
}

.test > img{ width:400px;} /* Elementos IMG que esten dentro de la clase TEST mediran 400px */

h1{
    text-align:center; /* Centrar texto */
    height:44px; /* Altura de la etiqueta H1 (OPCIONAL)*/
    color: #FFF; /* Color de tu texto */
    background-color: rgba(64, 185, 255, 0.8); /* Fondo azul del texto (OPCIONAL) */
}
</style>



<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
    <div class="popup" id="popup">
        <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 test">
                <img src="https://d39bmof8blmz8u.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Por-que-mi-gato-me-despierta-a-las-3am.png" id="img" href="img1.php">
                <h1>xx</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 test">
                <img src="https://d39bmof8blmz8u.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Por-que-mi-gato-me-despierta-a-las-3am.png" id="img" href="img2.php">
                <h1>xx</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cada imagen debe ir junto con el texto dentro de una etiqueta. En este caso, dentro de la etiqueta `test` estoy metiendo una imagen y un texto, dos veces. Tu estas colocando dos imagenes, y en la parte de abajo en otra etiqueta metes los textos,lo cual es posible pero no lo adecuado